# how to Create a trigger to copy attachment of lead to opportunity at the time of lead conversion

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, attachment, lead-conversion

I need to create trigger to copy attachment of lead to opportunity at the time of lead conversion.

Comment: Mind stating what you've tried and what part specifically you're facing troubles with ?

Comment: Hi @sumit, welcome to SFSE! Your question has been closed because it is asking for other people to write code for you, without presenting a real question or issue. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions that are real problems or errors. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at this blog post:http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/02/13/enhancing-the-lead-convert-process-in-salesforce. You could hook into it and copy the attachment over.

Comment: Great to see you on StackExchange Jeff!

Comment: Exactly my sentiments.  Glad to see more MVP's on here.  Followed your blog for years and have used your code snippets many times over.  Welcome to the party Jeff!

Comment: @Jeff Douglas .Welcome to stackexchange .Nice to see you .Stack community is lucky to have you here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger LeadConvert on Lead (after update) {

List<Attachment> lstattach=new List<Attachment>();

 // no bulk processing; will only run from the UI
 if (Trigger.new.size() == 1) {

   if (Trigger.old[0].isConverted == false && Trigger.new[0].isConverted == true) {

   // if a new opportunity was created
      if (Trigger.new[0].ConvertedOpportunityId != null) {

   for(Attachment a:[Select Id,ParentId from Attachment where ParentId=:Trigger.new[0].Id]){
      a.ParentId=Trigger.new[0].ConvertedOpportunityId;
      lstattach.add(a);
  }

   update lstattach;
 }

  }

 }
```

Here is the sample code which is not tested but it will give clear idea on how to proceed .